# ¿Cómo generar correctamente el interés compuesto en esta calculadora?

Tags: javascript

Yo estoy aprendiendo  y quiero armar una calculadora que me dé el interés compuesto de un número en cantidad de meses. Pero, no logro que se haga como corresponde. Adjunto mi código.

```js
let capital = prompt("capital");
let porcentage = prompt("ingresa el porcentage");
let meses = prompt("ingresa los meses");
for (let i = 0; i < meses.length; i++) {
  let intereses = parseInt(capital) * parseInt(porcentage) / 100;
  let interesYCapital = parseInt(intereses) + parseInt(capital);
  let total = parseInt(capital) + parseInt(interesYCapital) + parseInt(capital) * parseInt(porcentage) / 100;
  let final = parseInt(total) * parseInt(meses)
  document.write(final);
}
```

Comment: `meses.length` supone que meses es un array

Answer (score 1):

Se puede evitar iterar si aplicas la fórmula de interés compuesto, si en una iteración multiplicas lo mismo, se puede usar la potenciación. Dicho esto, entiendo que la fórmula es `MontoFinal = CapitalInicial × ( 1 + Interes_periodo ) ^ Períodos`, entonces:

```js
const capital = prompt("capital inicial");
const porcentaje = prompt("ingresa el porcentaje");
const meses = prompt("ingresa los meses");

const montoFinal = Math.round((capital*(1+(porcentaje/100))**meses) * 100) / 100;

alert(`Monto al finalizar los ${meses} períodos: ${montoFinal}`);
```

En cuanto al `parseInt`, no es necesario a menos que sumes, y en dicho caso se puede agregar un `+` al principio en lugar de `parseInt`.

En este caso, el interés devenga en el mismo intervalo que los períodos ingresados, pero podría no ser asi, Por ejemplo: Interés anual y período en meses, en dicho caso hay que cambiar la fórmula.

Answer (score 0):

No se muy bien como quieres calcular el interés compuesto. Pero en el bucle for, no puedes poner `meses.length` tendrás que poner parseInt(meses) ya que imagino que el usuario introducirá un numero.

Luego, no puedes declarar la variable que quieres que tenga el resultado global dentro del bucle, dado que en cada iteración perderás el dato de la anterior. Tendrás que declararla antes del bucle y en el for poner `final += total`, ya al rematar el bucle tendrás que poner `final = final * meses`.

Esto es algo teórico, dado que no se bien como se calcula el interés compuesto o lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score -1):

buff buff, menos mal que sólo hay 12 meses y no 100 o algo así, pues tu navegador se freiría cual tostadora, vamos con tu código:

```js
//Declaracion de variables siempre fuera de bucles, de lo contrario en cada vuelta irás fundiendo la memoria más y más y más (insisto, menos mal que sólo hay 12 meses)
let capital = prompt("capital");
let porcentage = prompt("ingresa el porcentage");
let meses = prompt("ingresa los meses");
let intereses
let interesYCapital;
let total;
let final = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(meses); i++) {
  intereses = parseInt(capital) * parseInt(porcentage) / 100;
  interesYCapital = parseInt(intereses) + parseInt(capital);
  total = (parseInt(capital) + parseInt(interesYCapital) +
    parseInt(capital) * parseInt(porcentage) / 100);
  final += total;
}
document.write(final);
```

Comment: **// TABULA POR DIOS** Este tipo de comentarios son innecesarios. Para orientar al OP puedes editar la pregunta e identar su código. Te aseguro que lo va a comprender y en preguntas futuras lo hará de manera correcta.

Comment: *buff buff, menos mal que sólo hay 12 meses y no 100 o algo así, pues tu navegador se freiría cual tostadora* -> Por qué, por iterar 4 o 5 veces un loop con operaciones aritméticas sencillas?? Si coges `meses` como string y usas el `meses.length`... si el usuario ha puesto 100 meses, va a iterar tres veces. Sinceramente, no me parece para tanto... incluso he hecho una prueba ahora en mi pc poniendo 9999 con su código y no es para tanto, sale instantáneo. Te recomiendo seguir además el consejo de @DjCrazy, y evitar todo tipo de comentario *jocoso* y/o que pueda resultar hiriente sin contexto.

Comment: No digo que en este caso lo vaya a freir, pero lo que pretendo es que comprenda que declarar variables dentro de bucles nunca se debe hacer. Y respecto al comentario no es jocos ni hiriente, simplemente pretendo que le llame la atención, porque el código queda mucho más claro, de todas formas, edito la respuesta y quito el comentario.